# HTML content in google apps script

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sites

how can I modify html code of gogle-site-page that was created with createPageFromTemplate methode?

Look at this:

This is how the page is created:

```
page.createPageFromTemplate(name,
                            ID,
                            template);
```

Now i need to add more html content:

```
var created_page = SitesApp.getPageByUrl(that page);

created_page.setHtmlContent(html code here);
```

But when I use this setHtmlContent meethode I rewrite the template code. How can I go around this? Is there some way I could just add HTML, not re-write it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

doing some string manipulation on a `var html = created_page.getHtmlContent()` is going to be the idea before setting it again.

Comment: `var created_page = SitesApp.getPageByUrl(new_page_url);
      var html_content = created_page.getHtmlContent();
      Logger.log(html_content);
      created_page.setHtmlContent("<p>Welcome to this page!</p>"+html_content);` I already did that, dosent work, the page dosent display anything, not new stuf, not even the loaded template.

Comment: why didn't you provide that line you already tried in your question? what appears in the log?

Comment: Because it didnt seem important when it is not working. It logs out html table code, but when i try to even copy it and than paste it behinde my template it dosent work ether