# Onclick in html code created by google apps script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sites

my problem is that i dont know how to call a onClick methode for  look at the code:

```
    var form = FormApp.openById(ID of form);
    var form_link = form.getPublishedUrl();
    var data = spred.getDataRange().getValues();
    var page = SitesApp.getPageByUrl(url of page);
    var url = "url of script with myFunction()";

    page.createWebPage(nazev,
    ID,
    "<a href="+form_link+" onclick=google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateButton).myFunction("+url+")>Ask for book</a>");
```

This does not work. What shall I do? Is there other way around? I found some but I they don't work ether. Here is link to the other way i could do this:[HTML content in google apps script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32110088/html-content-in-google-apps-script)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are creating new HTML code or a complete interface in your document, you should use Spreadsheet.getUi(). The code should be something similar to:

```
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Demo Button', 'menuItem1')
      .addToUi();
}

function menuItem1() {
  //Ask for a book
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately it dosent work. It gives me this error: The api method 'getUi' is only available in the new version of Google Sheets. (line 2, file "")